# Using nmap to detect realtime operating system

Tags: nmap, operating-systems

I would like to understand whether nmap can be used to detect the operating system type for realtime OS (Vxworks, threadx, free RTOS, etc.).

Has anyone done similar work before? Or if you have any idea how to do that, please share.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you think a realtime OS is different from an installed one? Are you looking for those OS's you list specifically? Have you looked up nmap's OS signature database?

Comment: The devices where the realtime OS runs are resource constrained & hence checking the feasibility of using this in a MCU. Sorry. I haven't looked up the nmap's OS signature database. I'm specifically interested to detect freertos,vxworks,threadx,qnx etc., 
there will be cases where the embedded devices might not use an RTOS. so running nmap shouldn't create any problem to such devices.